# Split line with spaces c#?

Tags: c#

I've the text in the following format in a file.

```
02-12-5-05-0108-000      2                  L
```

There are 6 spaces after -000 and 18 spaces after 2. I need the output as following,

```
02-12-5-05-0108-000
2
L
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `.Split(' ')`, I guess?

Comment: What have you tried?   _"best way"_ is subject to opinion and off topic for SO

Comment: Are you aware about the condition for split? is that based on more than one white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.Split(inputString, @"\s+")` will handle one or more space without the need to iterate and split on single space.

Answer (score 3):

what about:

```
var str = "02-12-5-05-0108-000      2                  L";
var lines = str.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(var s in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```